# How can I tell Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework to use stored procedures

Tags: asp.net, identity

I just got a project that has an up and running identity model using the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework 2.2.1  Everything works fine expect it's using Insert statements.  Is there a way I can override something to have it call my own procs or to make it use stored procedures?

Answer (score 1):

Using Fluent API you can specify to use stored procedures for your user entity.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    //...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Since it extends IdentityDbContext<T>
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .MapToStoredProcedures(s =>
            {
                s.Insert(i => i.HasName("insert_user"));
            });
    }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn468673.aspx

Comment: Wow, thank you.  I'm a dunce when it comes to EF.  Do I need to run this to as a separate step or is it just running as part of the normal application running?

Comment: No need for a separate step.
void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
"Typically, this method is called only once when the first instance of a derived context is created. The model for that context is then cached and is for all further instances of the context in the app domain."
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: I had to add this "base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);" to get it to not throw the error about "EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined" but it now runs.  The challenge now is trying to figure out what parameters it wants.  Unfortunately it doesn't just throw the proc at SQL so I can't trace it. I'm guessing it's just the properites of the Entity ApplicationUser.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot that it extends IdentityDbContext not DbContext. Updated answer.